# VBA Replace not considering Start argument

Tags: excel, vba, replace

Can someone help me fix the following code. I am trying to modify the first cell from the user's selection, so that it is absolute to the column only. (i.e. $A$1 to become $A1).

When using the below Replace function, it replaces both $ signs rather than just the 2nd...

```
var_address = Selection.Address

first_cell = Range(var_address).Cells(1, 1).Address
first_cell_new = Replace(first_cell, "$", "", Start:=2, Count:=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Replace(..., Start:=n, ...)` function removes the first `n` characters regardless what the function searches for.

Example:

```
Debug.Assert Replace("ABCDEF", "KLM", "XYZ", Start:=4) = "DEF"
Debug.Assert Replace("$AB$CD$EF", "$", "", Start:=4, Count:=1) = "CD$EF"
Debug.Assert Replace("$AB$CD$EF", "$", "", Start:=4, Count:=2) = "CDEF"
```

For your purpose, you need to combine `Left` and `Replace` functions:

```
var_address = "$A$1"
Debug.Print Left(var_address, 2) & Replace(var_address, "$", "", Start:=3) ' Count:=1 is useless here
```

See also Microsoft VBA documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function

Comment: Thank you for explaining how the Replace function works, I was not interpreting it correctly. I should have specified, but the user could technically select any range, so the code `Left(var_address, 2)` wouldn't work in my case if they selected cells $AZ$1:$BW$10. I think something like the following works for my needs: `first_cell_mod = StrReverse(Replace(StrReverse(first_cell), "$", "", 1, 1))` . Thanks again for your helpful reply!

Comment: Thanks for clarification. It's easier to use native `Address()` function to convert absolute addresses to relative addresses. See my other answer. Check it, vote and accept it if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, after you clarification in a comment under my previous answer, it's now more clearer. You actually want to change absolute addresses (e.g. `$A$1`) relative one (e.g. `$A1`, `A$1` or `A1`).

To do this, simply use the `Address` function and its parameters

```
var_address = Selection.Address   
first_cell = Range(var_address).Cells(1, 1).Address(False, True)
```